# Capture screenshot or record screen

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

i been looking at [hotjar](https://www.hotjar.com/) application and i got amazed of the feature that they have in capturing a video of the user interaction in a webpage. I felt that was great, but i wonder how would they make it, for example is hard to believe that they are recording the screen since i thinkg there are some restrictions in the browser, so i guess the would make like take a screenshot by second and track the mouse position (y,x), but this what i think. Doest anybody have a ideia how this functionality is made.